# How can we make sure that a 3rd party library doesn't send out user data in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, security, memory-management

If I need to include a 3rd Party SDK to connect to a wireless printer from within my iOS app, I suppose it's running in the same memory space of my code. How can I make sure that the SDK doesn't do any sneaky things in the background to steal user data within the app? Is there any network monitoring I can use to verify the network traffic of the app? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very hard to detect (unless you can analyze the source code).

1. You can run it in your iOS Simulator and analyze the network traffic with a [network sniffer].
   But still then: the app could only upload data when certain criteria are fulfilled (like it's between 01:00 and 04:00 in the night or whatever).
2. You could use [IDAPro](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) or another arm capable disassambler to reverse engineer your library and analyze what the library does exactly.

If you are lazy, you can open the library in a hex editor and search after text "http://" and look for possible url's. BUT THE LIBRARY COULD HIDE/crypt URL's! So. This is only for a lazy quick check.

Still remember: without reviewing the source-code you can never be absolutely sure about that.
So. Go for opensource libraries! :)

[1](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I always prefer open source libraries so I know what's under the hood when things go wrong. However, the device we use in the project is determined, so no good luck this time.

Answer (score 1):

For general traffic sniffing have a look at WireShark.
For HTTP sniffing I find Charles more convenient.

However, you can never know for certain what 3rd party code will do. For example, one could write a routine which only executes on production builds after a certain date.

Comment: It reminds me of taht old joke of information system deleting all data when a particular programmer is fired. I had some experience with WireShark, so I'll give Charles a try some time to see what's the difference. Thanks a lot!